# The values in async array.prototype.every return false, but function evaluates to true

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous

```
 return Dex.mod('gen9').species.all()
    .filter(pkmn => pkmn.isNonstandard === null)
    .filter(async pkmn => {
        const gens = new Generations(Dex);
        console.log(moveList.every(async (move) => gens.get(9).learnsets.canLearn(pkmn.name, move)));
        return moveList.every(async (move) => {
            console.log(pkmn.name, move, await gens.get(9).learnsets.canLearn(pkmn.name, move));
            await gens.get(9).learnsets.canLearn(pkmn.name, move)
        });
    });
```

I have tried everything I can think of, but I don't understand how the 2nd console.log can return false on some of the values, but the 1st console log can evaluate the complete .every call as true. How is this happening? I assume it has something to do with promises, but I have tried using .then, async/await (as shown), and still cannot get the filter to work properly.

I expect the moveList.every call to sometimes return false (if any of the values in the array evaluate to false), but it is returning true for all 700+ evaluations. I put the 2nd console.log in to check the values individually, and I can see that only 42 should be returned.

The line "gens.get(9).learnsets.canLearn(pkmn.name, move)" is asynchronous.

Comment: `every` doesn't take async callbacks. Nor does your callback even return anything but still - async functions produce promises -> promises are truthy.

Comment: Wait, why is that callback even async? You use `await` in it but in the console log above, you don't use await for the same code. If the code you await does not produce a promise, then why make it async?

Comment: I have to use async because the call 'gens.get(9).learnsets.canLearn(pkmn.name, move)' returns a promise. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong syntactically but I don't understand what it could be. What I'm Expecting:

the call to moveList.every returns an array of booleans, and if any of them are false, it evaluates to false and the filter omits it.

What I'm getting instead: every value returns true and the filter returns all 700+ values.